# Understanding angular $q promise chaining w.r.t particular example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I just a have a simple query related to this piece of code:

**Service Code :**

```
function getUser($q, $http) {
  return $http.get('...').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

**Controller Code :**

```
// getUser's consuming code
getUser().then(
  function(data) { // Success callback
    // Do something about data
  },
  function(response) { // Error callback
    // How does this error callback gets called ??
  }
);
```

In case some error occurs in the get users http call. I am not able to understand **how ( inner workings )** the error callback gets called in the controller.
The reason I am asking this is because I think we have to call the reject method ( on the deferred object ) in the **service then error callback** so that the **subsequent then error callback ( the one in controller )** is called.

i.e

```
function getUser($q, $http) {
  return $http.get('...').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  },function(response){
    return $q.reject(response)
  });
}
```

But how does the **controller's then error callback** is called when we don't return anything from the first then error callback ( the one inside the service ) which corresponds to an error.

Comment: That's how promises work. If you have code like `promiseA.then(promiseB).then(promiseC).then(promiseD).then(success,failure)` and `promiseB` rejects then `promiseC` and `promiseD` will be skipped and `failure` method will be executed

Comment: @KirillSlatin So, essentially if some error occurs, then the next available failure method is called irrespective of the fact that whether the next then method has it or any other then in the chain ??

Comment: yes, @bhavya_w, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

The inner workings are this: `then` returns a **new promise** which waits for the original promise to be settled, and

- if the original is resolved

  - if you've registered a resolution callback, calls your callback and resolves itself with the value the your callback returns
  - if you haven't registered a resolution callback, resolves itself with the original promise's resolution value
- if the original is rejected

  - if you've registered a rejection callback, calls your callback and rejects itself with the value your callback returns
  - if you **haven't** registered a rejection callback, rejects itself with the rejection value provided by the original promise

You can imagine the implementation of `then` being **very roughly**, *conceptually* along these lines:

```
function then(whenResolved, whenRejected) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        whenOriginalIsResolved(function(resolution) {
            if (typeof whenResolved === "function") {
                try {
                    resolution = whenResolved(resolution);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
            resolve(resolution);
        });
        whenOriginalIsRejected(function(rejection) {
            if (typeof whenRejected === "function") {
                try {
                    rejection = whenRejected(rejection);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
            reject(rejection);
        });
    });
}
```

Again, that's conceptual, not literal. If you want to see a literal implementation, the original Q by Kris Kowal implements it [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L831). (That's slightly more complex than the lightweight version Angular uses, but it's a good example.)

Comment: @bhavya_w: I'm talking per-promise. :-) Remember that your code is using **two** different promises (and creating a third, but unless you use the return value of `getUser.then`, we can ignore it). Promise 1 is the one you got from `$http`. Promise 2 is the one you got from calling `then` on Promise 1. Because your call to `$http.then` doesn't give a rejection handler, when `then` creates Promise 2 it sets that promise up to automatically reject itself if Promise 1 is rejected. E.g., the default is to chain.